# Get combo box selected value

Tags: jquery

I have a button that, when clicked, should get me the value of a combo box's selected item. For example, if I have the following combo and button:

```
<select id="client-sort-type">
    <option></option>
    <option>Name</option>
    <option>Recent</option>
</select>

<button id="client-sort-submit" type="button">Sort</button>
```

I want something like...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#client-sort-submit").click(function () {
        var val = $("#client-sort-type").attr("value");
        window.location.href = "Project/Index/" + val;
    });
</script>
```

Only this isn't working, it always returns nothing. Help?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist-using-jquery) This question has the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Your markup is not correct, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$("#client-sort-type").val()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters you should have `value=` in your `<options>`, otherwise it might generate unwanted behaviours.

**Use** `<option value="somevalue" >Name</option>`

**If** you want to get the value via jQuery you should use:

```
$("#client-sort-type").val(); // this will give you "somevalue"
```

**If** you want to get the text of the selected option use:

```
$("#client-sort-type option:selected").text(); // This will give you "Name"
```

Read the difference between **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706803/jquery-get-select-value)** and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist-using-jquery)**, if you keep your html as it is, it's better to use `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
val = $("#client-sort-type").attr("value");
```

use

```
val = $("#client-sort-type").val();
```