# jQuery retrieving select option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have tried using both of these methods and none seem to retrieve the selected value or text of from the drop down menu.

My HTML:

```
<select id="sessions">
  <option value="0">Choose a Session</option>
  <option value="Awesome">Awesome</option>
  <option value="test1">test1</option>
  <option value="testing">testing</option>
</select>
```

First Method:

```
var selectedSession = $('#sessions').options[$('#sessions').selectedIndex].val();
```

This doesn't even get recognized since I get a an undefined value returned.

Second Method:

```
var selectedSession = $('#sessions').find(":selected").text();
```

This returns the string "". A blank. I have tried both val() and text(). And yes, I know the difference between the two.

EDIT:

Tried all of these methods with no success:

```
var selectedSession = $('#sessions :selected').text();
var selectedSession = $('#sessions').val();
var selectedSession = $('#sessions option:selected').text();
var selectedSession = $('select#sessions').val();
var selectedSession = $('#sessions')[0].options[$('#sessions')[0].selectedIndex].val();
var selectedSession = document.getElementById("sessions").text(); Returns null
```

Also, to clarify, the javascript is in an external document (eg. external.js) and The variable is global and not inside any function.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: and/or [Get selected text from drop down list (select box) using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1643227/218196)

Comment: and/or [JQuery - Get select value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6706803/218196)

Comment: Also: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

to get **text** of option:

```
$( "#sessions option:selected" ).text();
```

to get **value** of option:

```
$('select#sessions').val()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Check the edit on my main post.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `val()` directly on the `select`

```
var selectedSession = $('#sessions').val();
```

The problem with your first method is that you're mixing up jQuery and native DOM methods, there is no `options` or `selectedIndex` property on a jQuery object, you'll have to do that on the select element itself. e.g. `$('#sessions')[0].options`, `$('#sessions')[0].selectedIndex`

Comment: Doesn't work. Check the edit on my main post.

Comment: You're probably trying to get the select before its created.

Comment: That could be the possible reason. Do you know how I can make it select after the document is loaded? i want to make this variable global.

Answer (score 0):

Try with $('select#sessions').val()

```
Here val is the value of the property
Here text is the value of the property.


Sample:
For val is '0', text is 'Choose a Session'
For val is 'Awesome' , text is Awesome.


Value represents option value
text represent the value between the tags. 


<select id="sessions">
  <option value="0">Choose a Session</option>
  <option value="Awesome">Awesome</option>
  <option value="test1">test1</option>
  <option value="testing">testing</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Check the edit on my main post.

Comment: .val is added, it should work now.

Comment: if you look at my post it tells you that I have already tried that.